# How do I download the "blpapi" Python library to use it with Bloomberg?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, bloomberg, blpapi

I attempted to use the query "from xbbg import blp," but encountered the following error message:
-> AttributeError: module 'blpapi' has no attribute 'session' (refer to the image below).

In my attempts to resolve this issue, I undertook the following steps:

1. I tried installing the "blpapi" Python library in my Anaconda environment using the commands `pip install blpapi` and `conda -c conda-forge blpapi`. However, this approach failed due to a network blockage preventing the download of external sites.
2. I installed "blpapipd" and "blpapi-stubs," both of which offer some similar functions. Unfortunately, even with these installations, the 'blp' import still did not function.
3. I downloaded the blpapi package directly from the official Bloomberg site and placed the folder in `/anaconda3/site-packages/folderX`. Regrettably, this did not resolve the problem.

If anyone has a small idea about how to resolve this issue, I open to suggestions.

Thanks.

You can see the image, it shows the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Kys.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the code and/or error as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pip install blpapi.

pip uninstall blpapi

Then run install via pip using

python -m pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi

That's the proper way to install blpapi. You can then use xbbg as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but it doesn’t work this way in my laptop. I can’t use pip install. The company I work for, do block any external download including pip install blpapi

Comment: You have python and xbbg installed, so you were able to access the internet at some point, neither can be installed without external access. Even JPM analysts can access the internet. Likely getting SSL errors when attempting to install. 

1. Set the http proxy using "set http_proxy=user:pass@host:port
2. or Turn off proxy
3. or Use vpn.